# Is rule selection in Drools nondeterministic or random?

Tags: drools

Consider in Drools a set of rules that make up an activation group, all of them have the same salience and all of them are activated. Because they are in an activation group, only one of them can fire.

I want to know if the Drools engine makes sure that each of these rules has approximately the same chance of firing (selection is random) or if it is only formally *undefined* which rule will fire (selection is nondeterministic). In the latter case the rule fired would depend on the machine's state if anything and in practice e.g. almost always the top rule will fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that there are n rules with equal salience with all of them being activated: there is no randomizing being done by the engine to select the next rule to be fired, i.e., you can't use the engine to select a winner in a lottery.

There is something like a priority queue, and new activations are entered according to some efficient procedure. You may read that code or devise some test to determine how, but you should not base your application on these findings.